# Using multiple PaaS Vendors

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, azure

I am developing a SaaS App, and I want to decide for a PaaS Vendor. Since one of my biggest concerns is uptime, is there an application or service, that allows me to use several PaaS Vendors (like Azure, Google App Engine, Amazon Web Services, etc.)?

I want my application to be able to respond from one PaaS Vendor to another almost instantly without any downtime, to use the redundancy that this provides. This means that I need to be able to use the different services homogeneously.

Comment: Every provider you mentioned already comes with distributed computing and failover facilities, so worrying about an additional layer of risk-spreading is IMHO not necessary. Choose the one best fitting your technical and monetary requirements and maybe ask about custom SLAs if their standards are not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna check out [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org/). It's an open-source PaaS and supports multiple cloud vendors including AWS, Azure, Openstack (including HP and Rackspace) and many others.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation (if any) to the site as the community tends to look down on self-promotion. See the [FaQ] for more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at RightScale http://www.rightscale.com/products/features/multi-cloud-engine.php  You can use AWS and RackSpace services on the RightScale Platform. With AWS you can use different availability zones. An availability zone can be thought of as a datacenter. If one goes down you'll have servers in another to handle requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for using multiple IaaS at the same time (vs PaaS). Google App Engine is a PaaS whereas Amazon Web Services and Rackspace are IaaS. To do that, you'll need a third party software that support multi-cloud deployment. RightScale is one of them, but I'll add [Scalr](http://scalr.net) to the list where I work.

That being said, all IaaS already offer failover solutions that allows you to avoid downtime. Depending on your projects, your infrastructure and your budget, using one IaaS rather than two maybe more efficient and what you should do.